# How to use progress bar with parallel.foreach?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, parallel.foreach

I have number of files to be downloaded and I have used Parallel.foreach in C#. It is working fine. Now I want to check the progress of download using progressbar. How is this possible?

I have used this code:

```
Parallel.For(0, numofitems, options, j =>
{
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
       client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);

       client.DownloadFile(list[j], @"F:\Test\Test2\a" + j + ".png"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? We like to see an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Please post it in your question. It's incredibly hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Whats wrong with what youve tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

1.Drop a progressbar into your form. In my example I leave the name it as is "progressBar1"

2.Add this change your DownloadProgressChanged event into the following

```
 client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
       {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
       };
```